# Args with function in Python

Tags: python, function, args

I started to learn Python and in exercises about args, I have this block of code, and I don't quite understand why we would define sum as 0 and then i as sum +=

```
def add(*args):
    sum = 0
    for i in args:
        sum += i
    return sum
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: (1) Suppose `args` is empty. Then the sum of the arguments is zero.  (2) Suppose it is not empty. If you don't start with `sum=0` then you will have to treat the first argument as different from all of the others: assign the first, then add the others.

Comment: If you don't set `sum` to `0` first, how are you going to add each argument to it?

Comment: btw `sum+=1` is just `sum = sum+i`, where sum is incremented by i

Comment: fwiw, `sum()` is a built-in function. 1) You can just use that 2) Don't name your own variables the same as built-ins

Comment: I don't think the proposed duplicate has anything to do with what the OP is asking.

Comment: We will never understand what the OP is asking until they respond. Everything else is speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*args` let's you send an undefined amount of arguments as a tuple. At the beginning of the function, where you want to obtain the sum, it's obviously 0 and then you update the value.

You can also write `sum+=i` as:

```
sum=sum+i
```

Let's do an small example, you do:

```
add(1,2,3)
```

It would look like:

1. You enter the function, sum is 0.
2. You iterate for every element of args (1,2,3).

```
Iteration 1: sum=0, i =1, sum=sum+i = 1

Iteration 2: sum=1 (updated last iteration doing 0+1) and i 2, we have sum=sum+i=3

Iteration 3 is 3+3 = 6
```

**Whats the advantage of using `*args`?**
Being able to send as many elements as you want without needing to modify the function.

Answer (score 0):

We'd like the following to be true when there is at least one argument:

```
add(x1, x2, ..., xn) == x1 + add(x2, ..., xn)
```

Eventually, though, we reach this case:

```
add(x1) == x1 + add()
```

What should `add` return with no arguments? Since `add(x1)` should clearly equal `x1`, we have to define `add() == 0`. This is because 0 is the *identity* for addition: `x + 0 == x` for any value of `x`.

Since your loop won't be entered at all when there are no arguments, we need to initialize `sum = 0` so that after we skip the loop, `return sum` will return `0` as required.

The loop itself is just adding numbers one after the other. If `args` is 1,2,3,4 then the function is equivalent to

```
sum = 0
sum += 1  # 0 + 1 == 1
sum += 2  # 1 + 2 == 3
sum += 3  # 3 + 3 == 6
sum += 4  # 6 + 4 == 10
return sum     # return 10
```